# Sequelize - To define foreign key, should I use references or belongsTo? or both?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

As far as I know, in sequelize, there are two ways to define foreign key.

First, use `references` like:

```
sequelize.define('foo', {
    bar_id: {
        type: 'blahblah',
        references: {
           model: Bar,
           key: 'id'
        }
    }
});
```

and second, use `belongsTo` method:

```
Foo.belongsTo(Bar, { foreignKey: 'bar_id', targetKey: 'id' });
```

Then when I define foreign key in a model, should I use one of them? or both?

- If I should use both, what is the difference between them?
- Or if `belongsTo` is enough for defining foreign key, can I remove the `bar_id` definition in `sequelize.define('foo', {...})`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to their doc, you can create the FK using references if you do not want to create associations and constraints. Otherwise use HasOne, HasMany, or BelongsTo.

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#enforcing-a-foreign-key-reference-without-constraints

Personally I have only used the HasOne, HasMany, and BelongsTo methods.

Probably a good idea to review the entire section on Associations at the above link.

Comment: You mean, I can use one of them and if I use a method like `belongsTo`, I don't have to define a property like `bar_id` for foreign key?

Comment: Yes, if you use BelongsTo, etc, Sequelize will create the foreign key fields and indexes for you and the fields will be in the model.

Comment: ... again please review the document link I posted - their documentation is pretty good and it details various options that allow you to control things as you need or prefer.