# how to create foreign keys using sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    const sequelize = require('../util/dbconnect');    
    const TableOne= sequelize.define('TableOne', {
          id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
          },
          awg: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false
          }
        });

        module.exports = TableOne;

        **Table 2:** 

        const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

        const sequelize = require('../util/dbconnect');

        const Tabletwo= sequelize.define('Tabletwo', {
          id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
          },
          item_des: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
          },
          gauge:{
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
          },
          connector_type:{
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
          }

        });

        module.exports = Tabletwo;
```

how to create a foreign key for two existing tables and link them, it would be great if it could be explained as I had gone through the documentation but couldn't work it out.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51865038/7482427) might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use belongsTo() notation for associating tables viz. foreign key.

`TableOne.belongsTo(Tabletwo); // Will add TabletwoId to TableOne`

OR

`TableOne.belongsTo(Tabletwo, {as: 'Two'}); // Adds TwoId to TableOne rather than TabletwoId`

You may refer https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/docs/associations/ for further details.